# Pandas resample interpolate behavior is odd

Tags: python, pandas

When asking pandas to resample this dataframe using interpolate it fails to do so properly simply propagating the first value forwards. Can someone explain this behavior? Using a recent version of pandas and using python 3.8

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'time': pd.to_timedelta([0., 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4], unit='s'), 'data':[100, 140, 50, 300, 400]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data).set_index('time')
df2 = df1.resample('1s').interpolate()
print(df1)
print(df2)
                        data
time                        
0 days 00:00:00          100
0 days 00:00:01.100000   140
0 days 00:00:02.200000    50
0 days 00:00:03.300000   300
0 days 00:00:04.400000   400
                  data
time                  
0 days 00:00:00  100.0
0 days 00:00:01  100.0
0 days 00:00:02  100.0
0 days 00:00:03  100.0
0 days 00:00:04  100.0
```

Comment: What would the expected output be? This doesn't look strange. If you resample at `second` level and everything is null except the first value 100, then it makes sense to only have 100s as linear interpolation given Xi = X(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first resample to a smaller unit and interpolate to get intermediate values. Then resample to seconds to get the data with equidistant timesteps.

```
df1.resample('ms').interpolate().resample('s').asfreq()
```

```
                       data
time                       
0 days 00:00:00  100.000000
0 days 00:00:01  136.363636
0 days 00:00:02   66.363636
0 days 00:00:03  231.818182
0 days 00:00:04  363.636364
```